# Session array with productids

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I'm adding product ids to a session array with:

```
if (isset($_GET["add"]) && (int)$_GET["add"]>0)
{
$_SESSION['products'][] = $_GET["add"];
}
```

How would I loop the array and add a class to all the products with the ids that are in the array?

Comment: Because you're referring to `$_GET` in lowercase maybe? I'd key the products array by `productId` rather than just adding them as a list so that to eliminate cycling / element search, and it should be more product+quantity compliant then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
...
$_SESSION['products'][$_GET["add"]] = true ;
...
```

Then simply ask

```
if ($_SESSION['products']) { something ... }
```

or in a loop

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $id=>$isset)
{
   // ...
}
```

btw shorter cond:

```
if (($_GET["add"]*1)>0)
```

Comment: Even shorter: `if($_GET["add"]*1>0)`. But seriously, you should use `isset` for variables that are not guaranteed to be existing. And your expression is also true for real numbers like `0.1`.